# phpspreadsheet merge error with variables

Tags: excel, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

When I'm merging cells with phpspreadsheet using a variable I have an issue.

On opening in MS Excel (2019), it says that the program can try to recover the document if I'm sure it's a reliable one.

When I say yes, the document is ok and the merging worked fine. 
Why do I have that message?

I don't have this message on this way :

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B2:F2');
```

But on this way I have this message :

```
$cellRange      =   'B2:F2';
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($cellRange);
```

Comment: Please note that I don't have any error message when I open this file on  openoffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was : 
I was using that merging tool on a "for" loop and I was trying to merge an already merged cell with another one.

Answer (score 1):

MergeCells is a sensible function. If you try to/accidentally make overlap cell groups this kind of error. Be sure that your code not do something like this:

```
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
  $cellRange      =   'B'.$i.':F'.$i;
  $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($cellRange);
}
```

Comment: Ok, yes my code is doing that, what do you suggest to fix it? 
I need to concatenate a variable, a ":" and another variable....

Comment: First step I would give out the cell ranges like B1:F1, B2:F2, C2:F2. Then i would take a look to where are the overlapping cells. In my exemple B2:F2, C2:F2. Then I would prevent this kind of merge (skip C2:F2). There are nice helper functions https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.html#method_mergeCells and https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.html#method_isInMergeRange